# Button wave effect not resetting with angular2 Materialize

Tags: html, css, angular, material-design, materialize

I use Materialize for angular2. The setup of the project :

- Angular2
- Angular-cli
- Webpack
- scss and ts

Here is the thing, when for example I create buttons like this :

```
<button class=" btn btn-large waves-effect waves-light col s12" type="submit">Valider</button>
```

or like this :

```
<a class=" btn btn-large waves-effect waves-light col s12" type="submit">Valider</a>
```

The ripple/wave effect from materialize play with a brighter color BUT it does not reset to the original color of the button.

Juste to be clear, it's for an authentification form. So the button is in a form

=> So if I click several time the color of the button becomes brighter and brighter until it become white...

**What could be wrong here ?**

Comment: Can you give a plnkr if possible

Comment: I'm not too familliar with plunker so i can't really reproduce it https://embed.plnkr.co/nPKDsGu79OoTXIlyTKlo/

Comment: I heard it can be an import issue, but I don't see how or where ? https://github.com/InfomediaLtd/angular2-materialize/issues/250

Comment: created a plnkr https://plnkr.co/edit/EKqE4c523bMoE8bKUPRE works fine here

Comment: That line in my index.html is causing the bug, but I don't understand why : <script type="text/javascript" src="./assets/js/bin/materialize.min.js"></script>

Comment: if your url is `localhost:3000` , what does this give `http://localhost:3000/assets/js/bin/materialize.min.js`

Comment: Check if you have the file in the exact path

Comment: That gives me the content of the file, which is present at the path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See https://github.com/Dogfalo/materialize/issues/2667 and https://github.com/Dogfalo/materialize/issues/4344

The problem is that the effect is stacked.
Did you try a new release of angular2-materialize?

Comment: I got the lastest version like 2 weeks ago

Comment: I guess they do not use materialize 0.99.0

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem here, It was because I was importing materialize more than one time (in some modules).